# htaccess add trailing slash and force www with clean urls

Tags: php, .htaccess

I'm using my htaccess file with mod_rewrite to create clean urls like this:

```
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
RewriteEngine On
RewriteBase /
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule . index.php [L]
</IfModule>
```

I would also like to force the site to have the 'www' subdomain and most importunately add a trailing slash if the url doesn't have one.

I am an absolute noob with mod_rewrite and I've tried accomplishing this on my own by combining other code I found on google (sad I know), but I always end up with a 500 error.

Here's the code I found for force www:

```
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
Options +FollowSymLinks
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^www\.domain\.tld$ [NC]
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ http://domain.tld/$1 [R=301,L]
</IfModule>
```

Thanks for your help.

Comment: Do either of them work alone? Find out which set of rules is breaking it.

Comment: I know the first one works, and I think the second one does too.  I'm just not sure how to combine it all to get the outcome I want.

Answer (score 11):

Try separating out the www and the trailing slash check.  This is tested and hopefully working for you.  You didn't say if you're running placing at domain root or in a subdirectory - usually good info when asking for help with htaccess.

```
RewriteEngine On

# Assuming you're running at domain root.  Change to working directory if needed.
RewriteBase /

#
# www check
# If you're running in a subdirectory, then you'll need to add that in
# to the redirected url (http://www.mydomain.com/subdirectory/$1

RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} !^www\. [NC]
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ http://www.mydomain.com/$1 [R=301,L]

#
# Trailing slash check

# Don't fix direct file links
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f

RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !(.*)/$
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ $1/ [L,R=301]

#
# Finally, forward everything to your front-controller

RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule .* index.php [QSA,L]
```

To debug, comment out the individual sections and see what is/isn't working.

Comment: Was this answer correct? I'm trying to accomplish the same myself (*except for the prepending `www`*) I cannot get this answer to work.

Comment: Tested and it still works fine for me.  What part exactly isn't working? The trailing slash, the forward to index.php, or the www?

Comment: Not working for me either. Redirects to complete server path of file!

Answer (score 2):

Use this and forgot your problems ;)

```
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
Options +FollowSymLinks
RewriteEngine On
RewriteBase /

RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^www\.(.*) [NC]
RewriteRule ^(.*?)/*$ http://%1/$1/ [L,R=301]

RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !(.*)/$
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ http://your-domain.ru/$1/ [L,R=301]

RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ /index.php/$1 [L]
</IfModule>
```