# .htaccess, multiple domains, non-www, force trailing slash, all redirect to PHP script

Tags: php, .htaccess, mod-rewrite

A challenge for some altruistic uber htaccess wizard gentleman:

I have been chipping away at a htaccess file for a new site I am working on and just can't crack it.  I have each segment working independently - but just cant get them all working together.  I am generating the site based on PHP REQUEST_URI.  Multiple domains are pointed at the same directory so it has to function for multiple domains.  I am trying to accomplish:

1. multiple domains pointed at same directory,
2. force non-www,
3. force trailing slash without extension, and
4. redirect all non-existent to a specific script

Essentially:

http://www.example.com/dog/cat -> 301 shows as -> http://example.com/dog/cat/ ->but silently redirects to -> http://example.com/script.php

OR

http://www.example.com/dog/cat/pig/bird/walrus -> 301 shows as -> http://example.com/dog/cat/pig/bird/walrus/ -> silently redirects to -> http://example.com/script.php

OR

http://www.example.com/dog/cat.html -> 301 shows as -> http://example.com/dog/cat/ -> silently redirects to -> http://example.com/script.php

OR

http://www.example.com/dog.php -> 301 shows as -> http://example.com/dog/ -> silently redirects to http://example.com/script.php

Thus far I have worked with the following snippets(from memory so forgive me):

Non-www:

```
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^www\.(.*)$ [NC]
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ http://%1/$1 [R=301,L]
```

Strip trailing slash:

```
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !(.*)/$
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ http://%{HTTP_HOST}/$1/ [L,R=301]
```

All non-existent to script:

```
RewriteCond %{SCRIPT_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteCond %{SCRIPT_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteRule ^.*/$ ./script.php [L]
```

I have had issues with specific parts not functioning at all, to recursive effects, etc.  I don't love asking for help, and I have done my best to do my homework, but I just can't figure this one out.

I have found similar questions here, such as:

[htaccess add trailing slash and force www with clean urls](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4410830/htaccess-add-trailing-slash-and-force-www-with-clean-urls)

Any help is greatly appreciated!

**UPDATE:**

So I have continued fiddling with the .htaccess file.  I added a comment below the question to the effect that I was having trouble with Firefox's "wonderful" address bar search feature redirecting the domain name to search when the domain was non-www and non-trailing slash.  Because of this, I changed my scheme to still be consistent (preventing duplicates) but do the opposite: force www and trailing slash.

The following code produces results near what I am looking for:

```
Options +FollowSymlinks
RewriteEngine On
RewriteBase /

#Redirect Forcing trailing slash
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteRule .*[^/]$ /$0/ [L,R=301]

#Redirect non-www to www
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} !^www\. [NC]
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ http://www.%{HTTP_HOST}/$1 [R=301,L]

#Redirect to script
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteRule ^.*$ script.php [L]
```

I still need the extension dropped off of non-existent files, i.e.:

www.example.com/cats.html -> www.example.com/cats/

Any advice would mean the world...

Comment: An interesting development.  It seems that when the url is stripped of both www and the trailing slash it sometimes is not recognized in the Mozilla Firefox 16.0.1 address bar as a domain.  It automatically forwards to search instead of checking the domain.  Based on this, I think the choice of action would be to rewrite to always INCLUDE the slash and always include the WWW.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have a problem with your strip trailing slash rule:

```
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !(.*)/$
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ http://%{HTTP_HOST}/$1/ [L,R=301]
```

You are matching the same trailing slash again, and adding another one in the redirect. Your target needs to be changed to:

```
RewriteRule ^(.*)/$ http://%{HTTP_HOST}/$1 [L,R=301]
```

This would have definitely caused a redirect loop. Otherwise, the only other problem that may have been an issue is using `%{SCRIPT_FILENAME}` instead of `%{REQUEST_FILENAME}`. In most cases, it shouldn't make a difference, but the second one is probably what you really want:

```
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteRule ^.*/$ ./script.php [L]
```

None of these rules should conflict with each other as long as the 2 redirect rules are **before** the routing to `script.php` rule. It's working fine in my blank htaccess file on a vanilla apache install.

Comment: @SamanthaP re: your previous comment. Yeah I missed that. it shouldn't have had the `!` at all